# How to get the greatest of the dates comparing two columns with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

1.I have a DF where the date should always be greater than cop_date and fat_date.

2.If fact is nan it should still fetch date greater than cop_date

3.only consider the recent lesser date.

Actual DF:

```
id  ins_id  date    cop cop_date    fat fat_date
1234    abc 17/04/2023  1   18/05/2023  nan nan
1234    abc 16/04/2023  1   12/03/2023  nan nan
1234    abc 18/04/2023  1   23/03/2023  nan nan
1234    ghi 22/06/2023  1   27/08/2023  2   15/09/2023
1234    ghi 23/06/2023  1   22/05/2023  2   20/10/2023
1234    ghi 26/06/2023  1   19/04/2023  2   30/04/2023
1234    jkl 22/08/2023  1   26/08/2023  nan nan
1234    jkl 17/08/0223  1   13/08/2023  nan nan
1234    mno 06/05/2023  1   09/05/2023  2   10/05/2023
1234    mno 04/05/2023  1   01/05/2023  2   01/04/2023
```

Expected DF:

```
id  ins_id  date    cop cop_date    fat fat_date
1234    abc 17/04/2023  1   12/03/2023  nan nan
1234    abc 16/04/2023  1   12/03/2023  nan nan
1234    abc 18/04/2023  1   12/03/2023  nan nan
1234    ghi 22/06/2023  1   19/04/2023  2   30/04/2023
1234    ghi 23/06/2023  1   19/04/2023  2   30/04/2023
1234    ghi 26/06/2023  1   19/04/2023  2   30/04/2023
1234    jkl 22/08/2023  1   13/08/2023  nan nan
1234    jkl 17/08/0223  1   13/08/2023  nan nan
1234    mno 06/05/2023  1   01/05/2023  2   01/04/2023
1234    mno 04/05/2023  1   01/05/2023  2   01/04/2023
```

Query I tried:

```
Data =DF[(DF[`date`] > DF[`cop_date`]) & (DF[`date`] > DF[`fat_date`])]

Data= data.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','ins_id','date'],keep='first')
```

The above query eliminated the row wch has nan value.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to write a good pandas question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

First convert columns from list `dates` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
dates = ['date','cop_date','fat_date']
df[dates] = df[dates].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Then convert not less values in `cop` and `fat` dates to missing values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and get minimal values per groups in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `min`:

```
cols = ['id','ins_id']

m1 = df['cop_date'].lt(df['date'])
m2 = df['fat_date'].lt(df['date'])

df[['cop_date','fat_date']] = (df.assign(cop_date = df['cop_date'].where(m1),
                                         fat_date = df['fat_date'].where(m2))
                                 .groupby(cols)[['cop_date','fat_date']]
                                 .transform('min'))

df[dates] = df[dates].apply(lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print (df)
     id ins_id        date  cop    cop_date  fat    fat_date
0  1234    abc  17/04/2023    1  12/03/2023  NaN         NaN
1  1234    abc  16/04/2023    1  12/03/2023  NaN         NaN
2  1234    abc  18/04/2023    1  12/03/2023  NaN         NaN
3  1234    ghi  22/06/2023    1  19/04/2023  2.0  30/04/2023
4  1234    ghi  23/06/2023    1  19/04/2023  2.0  30/04/2023
5  1234    ghi  26/06/2023    1  19/04/2023  2.0  30/04/2023
6  1234    jkl  22/08/2023    1  13/08/2023  NaN         NaN
7  1234    jkl  17/08/2023    1  13/08/2023  NaN         NaN
8  1234    mno  06/05/2023    1  01/05/2023  2.0  01/04/2023
9  1234    mno  04/05/2023    1  01/05/2023  2.0  01/04/2023
```

How it working:

```
print (df.assign(cop_date = df['cop_date'].where(m1),
                 fat_date = df['fat_date'].where(m2)))
     id ins_id       date  cop   cop_date  fat   fat_date
0  1234    abc 2023-04-17    1        NaT  NaN        NaT
1  1234    abc 2023-04-16    1 2023-03-12  NaN        NaT
2  1234    abc 2023-04-18    1 2023-03-12  NaN        NaT
3  1234    ghi 2023-06-22    1        NaT  2.0        NaT
4  1234    ghi 2023-06-23    1 2023-04-19  2.0        NaT
5  1234    ghi 2023-06-26    1 2023-04-19  2.0 2023-04-30
6  1234    jkl 2023-08-22    1        NaT  NaN        NaT
7  1234    jkl 2023-08-17    1 2023-08-13  NaN        NaT
8  1234    mno 2023-05-06    1        NaT  2.0        NaT
9  1234    mno 2023-05-04    1 2023-05-01  2.0 2023-04-01
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael is it possible to use conditional statement like below ?  Data =DF[((DF[`date`] > DF[`cop_date`]) | (DF['fat'].isna())) & (DF[`date`] > DF[`fat_date`])]   and then drop duplicates by sorting cop_date and fat_date ?

Comment: @AravindBalakrishnan - Yes, it is possible, seems need `Data =df[((df['date'] > df['cop_date']) & (df['date'] > df['fat_date'])) | (df['fat'].isna() & (df['date'] > df['cop_date']))]`, but ouput is different like in question.